# Android application is not opening on emulator and real phone

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, myo

i have a problem in running my App on the simulator or even the real android phone even there are no syntax errors, when i run the vertual phone it opens but the application don't work and i get the message `"can't initialize HUB"` as in the image, and i get on console the following logs :

```
08-14 19:40:23.271 2342-2357/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld V/RenderScript: 0xae4be000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
08-14 19:40:24.090 2342-2357/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4b12a0
08-14 23:40:24.165 5064-5078/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                                     [ 08-14 23:40:24.192  5064: 5064 D/         ]
                                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa9e81f0, tid 5064
08-14 23:40:24.556 5064-5078/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-14 23:40:25.289 5064-5078/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld V/RenderScript: 0xae5b7000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
08-14 23:40:25.433 5064-5078/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4b12a0
08-14 23:40:28.898 5064-5070/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld W/art: Suspending all threads took: 65.953ms
08-14 23:40:28.950 5064-5064/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld E/Hub: Bluetooth not supported
08-14 23:40:30.344 5064-5064/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-14 23:40:31.042 5064-5078/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4b10e0
```

[image]

my source code is :

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 Thalmic Labs Inc.
 * Distributed under the Myo SDK license agreement. See LICENSE.txt for details.
 */

package com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.thalmic.myo.AbstractDeviceListener;
import com.thalmic.myo.Arm;
import com.thalmic.myo.DeviceListener;
import com.thalmic.myo.Hub;
import com.thalmic.myo.Myo;
import com.thalmic.myo.Pose;
import com.thalmic.myo.Quaternion;
import com.thalmic.myo.XDirection;
import com.thalmic.myo.scanner.ScanActivity;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mLockStateView;
    private TextView mTextView;

    // Classes that inherit from AbstractDeviceListener can be used to receive events from Myo devices.
    // If you do not override an event, the default behavior is to do nothing.
    private DeviceListener mListener = new AbstractDeviceListener() {

        // onConnect() is called whenever a Myo has been connected.
        @Override
        public void onConnect(Myo myo, long timestamp) {
            // Set the text color of the text view to cyan when a Myo connects.
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

        // onDisconnect() is called whenever a Myo has been disconnected.
        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(Myo myo, long timestamp) {
            // Set the text color of the text view to red when a Myo disconnects.
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        // onArmSync() is called whenever Myo has recognized a Sync Gesture after someone has put it on their
        // arm. This lets Myo know which arm it's on and which way it's facing.
        @Override
        public void onArmSync(Myo myo, long timestamp, Arm arm, XDirection xDirection) {
            mTextView.setText(myo.getArm() == Arm.LEFT ? R.string.arm_left : R.string.arm_right);
        }

        // onArmUnsync() is called whenever Myo has detected that it was moved from a stable position on a person's arm after
        // it recognized the arm. Typically this happens when someone takes Myo off of their arm, but it can also happen
        // when Myo is moved around on the arm.
        @Override
        public void onArmUnsync(Myo myo, long timestamp) {
            mTextView.setText(R.string.hello_world);
        }

        // onUnlock() is called whenever a synced Myo has been unlocked. Under the standard locking
        // policy, that means poses will now be delivered to the listener.
        @Override
        public void onUnlock(Myo myo, long timestamp) {
            mLockStateView.setText(R.string.unlocked);
        }

        // onLock() is called whenever a synced Myo has been locked. Under the standard locking
        // policy, that means poses will no longer be delivered to the listener.
        @Override
        public void onLock(Myo myo, long timestamp) {
            mLockStateView.setText(R.string.locked);
        }

        // onOrientationData() is called whenever a Myo provides its current orientation,
        // represented as a quaternion.
        @Override
        public void onOrientationData(Myo myo, long timestamp, Quaternion rotation) {
            // Calculate Euler angles (roll, pitch, and yaw) from the quaternion.
            float roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(Quaternion.roll(rotation));
            float pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(Quaternion.pitch(rotation));
            float yaw = (float) Math.toDegrees(Quaternion.yaw(rotation));

            // Adjust roll and pitch for the orientation of the Myo on the arm.
            if (myo.getXDirection() == XDirection.TOWARD_ELBOW) {
                roll *= -1;
                pitch *= -1;
            }

            // Next, we apply a rotation to the text view using the roll, pitch, and yaw.
            mTextView.setRotation(roll);
            mTextView.setRotationX(pitch);
            mTextView.setRotationY(yaw);
        }

        // onPose() is called whenever a Myo provides a new pose.
        @Override
        public void onPose(Myo myo, long timestamp, Pose pose) {
            // Handle the cases of the Pose enumeration, and change the text of the text view
            // based on the pose we receive.
            switch (pose) {
                case UNKNOWN:
                    mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.hello_world));
                    break;
                case REST:
                case DOUBLE_TAP:
                    int restTextId = R.string.hello_world;
                    switch (myo.getArm()) {
                        case LEFT:
                            restTextId = R.string.arm_left;
                            break;
                        case RIGHT:
                            restTextId = R.string.arm_right;
                            break;
                    }
                    mTextView.setText(getString(restTextId));
                    break;
                case FIST:
                    mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.pose_fist));
                    break;
                case WAVE_IN:
                    mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.pose_wavein));
                    break;
                case WAVE_OUT:
                    mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.pose_waveout));
                    break;
                case FINGERS_SPREAD:
                    mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.pose_fingersspread));
                    break;
            }

            if (pose != Pose.UNKNOWN && pose != Pose.REST) {
                // Tell the Myo to stay unlocked until told otherwise. We do that here so you can
                // hold the poses without the Myo becoming locked.
                myo.unlock(Myo.UnlockType.HOLD);

                // Notify the Myo that the pose has resulted in an action, in this case changing
                // the text on the screen. The Myo will vibrate.
                myo.notifyUserAction();
            } else {
                // Tell the Myo to stay unlocked only for a short period. This allows the Myo to
                // stay unlocked while poses are being performed, but lock after inactivity.
                myo.unlock(Myo.UnlockType.TIMED);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

        mLockStateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lock_state);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // First, we initialize the Hub singleton with an application identifier.
        Hub hub = Hub.getInstance();
        if (!hub.init(this, getPackageName())) {
            // We can't do anything with the Myo device if the Hub can't be initialized, so exit.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't initialize Hub", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Next, register for DeviceListener callbacks.
        hub.addListener(mListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // We don't want any callbacks when the Activity is gone, so unregister the listener.
        Hub.getInstance().removeListener(mListener);

        if (isFinishing()) {
            // The Activity is finishing, so shutdown the Hub. This will disconnect from the Myo.
            Hub.getInstance().shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (R.id.action_scan == id) {
            onScanActionSelected();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onScanActionSelected() {
        // Launch the ScanActivity to scan for Myos to connect to.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Hub` and why is `hub.init(this, getPackageName())` returning `false`?

Comment: @mohammad If one of these answers, answered your question, please mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to establish a connection to your Myo. The hub can't be initialished. According to the [documentation](https://developer.thalmic.com/docs/api_reference/android/classcom_1_1thalmic_1_1myo_1_1_hub.html#a91352ca197594c1cd447755d83d0b4e1) this occurs when your Android device doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy. Bluetooth is not supported in the [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html), because of this the initialization will fail.

Creating a connection will also fail if the applicationIdentifier is not properly formatted, but in that case you should get an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

Device recommended be Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) and up and device must have Bluetooth radio that supports Bluetooth 4.0 LE! Emulator not supported Bluetooth 4.0 LE. You say your Android application is not opening on emulator and real phone. Check on your real phone version of Android and if phone support Bluetooth 4.0 LE. Check FAQs from Myo support: [What devices is the Myo armband compatible with](https://support.getmyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/202773768-What-devices-is-the-Myo-armband-compatible-with-).